# Docker: How to install OpenJDK JRE 12 on top of Debian jessie-slim?

Tags: java, docker, debian, debian-jessie

I am trying to install OpenJDK JRE 12 on top of `debian:jessie-slim` image.

In the end, I need to install the [openjdk-12-jre-headless](https://packages.debian.org/sid/openjdk-12-jre-headless) package. However, I am getting:

> E: The value 'openjdk-12-jre-headless' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources

I have tried different options, but it looks like I am doing something wrong.

**My Dockerfile** is quite complex, but the issue is reproducible with this one:

```
FROM debian:jessie-slim
RUN apt-get install -y --target-release openjdk-12-jre-headless
```

Comment: Could you please show us your .Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I managed to install this jre distribution on image that you provided with given Dockerfile :

```
FROM debian:jessie-slim
RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get -y upgrade && \
 echo 'deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main' >> '/etc/apt/sources.list' && \
 apt-get -y update && \
 mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 && \
 apt-get -y install openjdk-12-jre-headless
```

I had to add repository from [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/openjdk-12-jre-headless/download) to `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. This is for amd64 jre distribution so if you want a different one just check the bottom of [this page](https://packages.debian.org/sid/openjdk-12-jre-headless) and add mirror for the version you want, like I did in my Dockerfile. Additionaly I had to create folder `/usr/share/man/man1` because of [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=863199).

Finally I run the container with this image and checked java version :

```
openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12-Debian-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12-Debian-1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1` is the secret unexpected ingredient that helped me out.